# Wordpress Database Gone but Site Online... Rebuild Possible?

Tags: database, wordpress, hosting, mediatemple

The database for my site `yokebreak.com` has gone AWOL.

No idea how or why, and my host MediaTemple claims not to have any backups nor have they made any effort to explain what happened.

(VERY VERY disappointed in the previously great MT customer service right now as it's been almost a week with no real answers.)

Anyway, what's done is done, and now I need to get the site rebuilt.

Considering the cached site and all the content is still online, I was wondering if anybody had an ideas or experience for restoring a DB from a still-live wordpress site?

Is this even possible or at the very least is there a faster way to get this done than copying and pasting old content?

Any tips or advice is much, much appreciated! Thanks!

Cheers,
Kyle Duck

Comment: It's late but are you saying that the WordPress site is still live? So how does the database considered as lost?

Comment: it was still live because i was using some cache plugins

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, if your database is completely gone and you are looking at a cached version of the website, there will not be a way recover the database except from some form of backup.

As you have stated there is no backup available, the best thing you can do is to try and salvage as much of the site as possible from any sources where content might reside such as saving images from the cached version, copying and pasting text, or perhaps you or someone else involved in the original build may still have content, images, text, files on an offline disk.

Comment: Thanks, galtech. Was afraid of this answer =)

Comment: Am doing a complete mirror of the site with the excellent httrack at the moment. So,there's that. Heh. Cheers http://www.httrack.com/